# iOS: How to use photos Framework (iOS 8.0)?

Tags: ios, photokit

How to use photos `Framework (iOS 8.0)`? I wanna get one result that can show one by one image in the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: "get one result that can show one by one image in the UICollectionView" what you mean ? get from where ?

Comment: How to display pictures one by one in the UICollectionView ？Not all the photos displayed at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fetchResult with all images, you can solve it like this:

```
// Property in your UICollectionViewController.h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) PHFetchResult *allPhotosFetchResult;

// In your awakeFromNib or where you refresh your Data
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
self.allPhotosFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:allPhotosOptions];
```

In your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method you can access the asset with

```
self.allPhotosFetchResult[indexPath.row];
```

To get the number of rows in collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:

```
self.allPhotosFetchResult.count
```

Comment: thank you very much ! But How to display pictures one by one in the UICollectionView ？Not all the photos displayed at once

Comment: What do you mean with "one by one"? Each cell displays one asset/image.
Everything else is based on your cellSize and CollectionViewLayout.

You should really clarify your question above.

Comment: I am so sorry about this.Thank you very much ,I have already solve this issue. Wish U have a great day~